# Show that the derivative of $g(x) = xf(x)$ is $g'(x) = xf'(x) + f(x)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Show that the derivative of $g(x) = xf(x)$ is $g'(x) = xf'(x) + f(x)$ by definition.

Thanks!

Comment: Take a time to read this: http://www2.clarku.edu/~djoyce/ma120/derivatives2.pdf

Comment: Are you allowed to assume the product rule?

Comment: Does "by definition" mean *by the limit definition*?

Comment: Ahh, my bad! Yes I have to show it by the limit definition.

Comment: @PureRushh Have you set up the difference quotient?  If so, where are you stuck?

Answer (score 3):

$$\underset{h\to 0}{\mathop{\lim }}\,\frac{(x+h)f(x+h)-xf(x)}{h}=\underset{h\to 0}{\mathop{\lim }}\,\left( \frac{xf(x+h)-xf(x)}{h}+\frac{hf(x+h)}{h} \right)=xf'(x)+f(x)$$

Answer (score 0):

Use that $\underset{x\rightarrow x_{0}}{lim}\frac{g(x)-g(x_{0})}{x-x_{0}} = g'(x_{0}) $ (the definition for $g'(x_{0})$) for your function $g(x)=xf(x)$.
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

By definition,

$$g'(x)=\lim_{t\to x}\frac{g(t)-g(x)}{t-x}$$

$$=\lim_{t\to x}\frac{\left(tf(t)-xf(t)\right)+\left(xf(t)-xf(x)\right)}{t-x}$$

$$=\lim_{t\to x}\left(f(t)+x\frac{f(t)-f(x)}{t-x}\right)$$

$$=f(x)+xf'(x)$$

Comment: Did you use L'Hôpital's rule on the last limit?

Comment: @PureRushh the definition of $f'(x)$